# How to volume up in application android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, volume, application-settings

My application is a soundbox and my problem is I can't volume up when any sounds is playing.

I mean, if you volume up while there is no media playing, it only volumes up the volume of the telephone (calls...)

How can I fix it ?
Is there any properties in android manifest which turns my application into a " media " application ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are advised to google first, before posting on SO.

With little googling, this info is available :

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

And

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//Volume up:
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
//Volume down:
audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me !

Comment: @Slamingzone If my answer was the one that worked for you, please consider accepting it as the answer of choice by clicking on the "Green Tick" mark next to the answer. It gives both of us some reputation, and also tells other users that your problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

By AudioManager you can control the volume of media player.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
```

Note:This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use adjustStreamVolume(int, int, int) with ADJUST_MUTE or ADJUST_UNMUTE instead.

Answer (score 0):

Android uses different streams for playing different kind of sounds, so you can't really "volume up in application". What you can do is adjusting/setting the volume of a particular stream. [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) is your friend.

For example, if you play some music using a `MediaPlayer` instance, you could call [adjustStreamVolume(int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) OR [adjustStreamVolume(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustVolume%28int,%20int%29) OR [setStreamVolume(int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume%28int,%20int,%20int%29) on an `AudioManager` instance.

Calling `adjustStreamVolume(int, int)` will affect the volume of the "the most relevant" stream, so you don't need to specify a stream manually.